# Size inspector not working in Xcode: there are no options showing

Tags: ios, xcode

I have added a `UIViewController` in the storyboard. And when I tried to change its size, there are no options showing in the size inspector. The attributes inspector also shows nothing. The xcode version that I am using is 9.4.1. It was working before.
[image]

Comment: Because you didn't select any view. There is no size for scene.

Comment: @Kamran No, because I can change to freeform by selecting the viewcontroller. It is not working. Also I selected the view and it shows nothing too.

Comment: @NaderBesada, No, It's not true. You can resize view controller.

Comment: Sometimes it happed with me also, What I was doing close the current tab and open a new tab.

Comment: @Bali Yes, i got it, you want to change the frame. But i can see that option on my machine Xcode 9.4.1. May be restarting xcode can do some trick.

Comment: @MahendraGP Thank You. It worked!!!  Before, I have restarted the XCode, even restarted the machine, but didn't worked. But simply by opening a new tab worked!!!!

Comment: If you showed Document Outline, there would be no confusion as to what is currently selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it happens with the Xcode, it seems the bug in it.

*The solution is*

**Just close the current tab and open a new tab. Now Size inspector, attribute inspector, etc. will be shown.**

Answer (score 1):

Sometime its Xcode Bug, Just close current tab and open new … Hopefully you will see the Size Inspector.

---

### Work with View Controllers

If you will still face the problem follow the below instructions to test your Xcode is working properly and you are using ode in proper way.

> For this, you’ll use an image view (UIImageView), a user interface
>   element that displays a picture.

To add an image view to your scene

1. Open your storyboard, Main.storyboard.
2. Open the Object library in the utility area. (Alternatively, choose
   View > Utilities > Show Object Library.)
     ￼

[image]

3. In the Object library, type image view in the filter field to find
   the Image View object quickly.
4. Drag an Image View object from the Object library to your scene so
   that it’s in the stack view below the button.
     ￼

[image]

5. With the image view selected, open the Size inspector ￼ in the
   utility area. 
    Recall that the Size inspector appears when you select the fifth
   button from the left in the inspector selector bar. It lets you edit
   the size and position of an object in your storyboard.
    ￼

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 14.3.1 I could not get it working again. Downgrading to Xcode 14.0 solved it.